# Xcode 7 build failed Id: library not found for -IPods clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: build, linker

Trying to update a new version of app I bought in auction and the build fails, any idea?

Comment: Please, add some more info about your problem, be specific, what you are trying to do, what is the problem?

Comment: I'm really new to coding, I get this error and have no idea of where to start to try and fix.

Comment: Id: library not found for -IPods clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I bought the app and wanted to update the name and make it compatible for iPhone. Didn't change anything from the original code, the app is published and works fine, but I can't make any updates.